# Pushing back elements in c++ std::vector, they lose information

Tags: c++, inheritance, stdvector

I'm working on a pre-existing code and checking if it works.

With my greatest surprise, these basic classes are giving me troubles

```
typedef int Id;
typedef int BcId;

//!  This class gives some common methods to all mesh objects.
class Identifier{
public:

    static const UInt NVAL;

    Identifier(UInt id):id_(id),bcId_(NVAL){}
    Identifier(UInt id, UInt bcId):id_(id),bcId_(bcId){}

    bool unassignedId()const {return id_==NVAL;}
    bool unassignedBc()const {return bcId_==NVAL;}

    Id id() const {return id_;}
    BcId bcId() const {return bcId_;}
    Id getId() const {return id_;}


    protected:
    Id id_;
    BcId bcId_;
};


//!  This class implements a 3D point, the default is z=0 => 2D point
class Point: public Identifier{
public:

    static const UInt ndim = 3;

    Point(): Identifier(NVAL, NVAL){coord_.resize(3);};
    Point(Real x, Real y, Real z=0):Identifier(NVAL, NVAL)
        {coord_.resize(3);coord_[0]=x; coord_[1]=y; coord_[2]=x;}
    Point(Id id, BcId bcId, Real x, Real y, Real z=0):Identifier(id, bcId)
        {coord_.resize(3);coord_[0]=x; coord_[1]=y; coord_[2]=z;}
    void print(std::ostream & out) const;
    Real operator[](UInt i) const {return coord_[i];}

    private:
    std::vector<Real> coord_;

};

void Point::print(std::ostream & out) const
{
out<<"Point -"<< id_ <<"- "<<"("<<coord_[0]<<","<<coord_[1]<<","<<coord_[2]<<")"<<std::endl<<"------"<<std::endl;
}
```

Now with the simplest test:

```
int main()
{
    Point a(1,1,0,0);
    Point b(2,2,0,1);
    Point c(3,3,1,0);

    a.print(std::cout);
    b.print(std::cout);
    c.print(std::cout);

    std::cout<<b.getId()<<std::endl;
    b.print(std::cout); 

    std::vector<Point> points;
    points.resize(3);
    points.push_back(c);
    points.push_back(b);
    points.push_back(a);


    std::cout<<"The points are"<<std::endl;
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
        points[i].print(std::cout);
    std::cout<<std::endl;

}
```

I get the output:

```
Point -1- (0,0,0)
------
Point -2- (0,1,0)
------
Point -3- (1,0,0)
------
2
Point -2- (0,1,0)
------
The points are
Point -2147483647- (0,0,0)
------
Point -2147483647- (0,0,0)
------
Point -2147483647- (0,0,0)
```

Comment: What do you think about this `points.resize(3);`?

Comment: Hint, `for (int i=3; i<6; ++i)`

Comment: So damn stupid :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is you used `points.resize(3);` instead of `points.reserve(3);`.  [`std::vector:::resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) will change to size of the vector to the size provided.  If the vector grows then it insert the necessary default constructed objects.  In this case that means the first 3 elements of the vector are default constructed and the 3 points you push into it are actually in index's `[3, 5]`.

If you had called [`std::vector::reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) then it would have allocated the space for 3 objects but not create any default instances.  That means when you push the points back the will occupy index's `[0, 2]`

Answer (score 1):

[vector::resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) is not the right function, it actually resizes the array, push_back then adds *another* three elements to it.

You probably meant to use [vector::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve).